# Web project to deploy on tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I'm getting the following error on default Vaadin code with Tomcat 7.

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - The type java.util.function.Consumer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
     required .class files
    - The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.function.Consumer` seems to be coming from `Java 8`.
Have you deployed the app using JDK 8 ?